# Running NestJS Kafka consumer in Nest Application rather than Nest Microservice

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs

I have a fairly simple Nest microservice that looks something like:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(EventModule, microserviceConfig)
  await app.listen()
}

bootstrap();
```

I have my various Kafka transport and options configured in `microserviceConfig`.  I can then listen to messages coming in on a topic using a very simple controller:

```
@Controller()
export class EventController {
  constructor(private readonly eventService: EventService) {}

  @EventPattern("ITEM_CREATED")
  async handleClientRelationshipCreated(@Ctx() ctx : KafkaContext) {
    console.log(ctx.getTopic())
    this.eventService.handleMessage(ctx.getMessage())
  }
}
```

This works great, however I'd like to use the same code in a Nest Application:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  bufferLogs: true,
});
```

When I add my Kafka configuration to my app module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'my-service',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
// ...
```

The app runs, but I don't see any sort of Kafka initialization in the logs nor does it receive any messages.  I'm guessing the Kafka library is built around microservices and doesn't support Nest applications.

Question:

What's the easiest approach to consume Kafka messages in a Nest application?  Porting my app over to a microservice would not be trivial, for example we use a bunch of app middleware which isn't supported in microservices.

Is it possible to run the Kafka consumer somewhere and just start it up manually in some sort of background worker?  Are there any existing libraries that allow consumption of Kafka messages in a Nest application?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  Running a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application) is the solution here!

I simply run:

```
app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,

      options: {
// ...
```

And then:

```
await app.startAllMicroservices();
```

Now my normal Nest application and my Kafka based microservice run all in one process.